# Isomorphism in regular graphs

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

Let $G$ be a connected regular graph. Consider two different vertices $u,v$ of $G$. Let $H_1$ be the graph obtained from $G$ by deleting vertex $u$, and $H_2$ be the graph obtained from $G$ by deleting vertex $v$. Is it necessary that $H_1$ and $H_2$ are isomorphic?

Comment: First you can ask yourself: is a connected regular graph necessarily vertex-transitive? The answer is no and if you start from those counterexamples then you will work out a counterexample to your question.

Comment: the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frucht_graph is a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

No, they're not necessarily isomorphic. For easy counterexamples look at the disjoint union of two different regular graphs of the same degree (e.g. different cyclic graphs), then delete a point from each of the graphs.

Comment: Sorry. I meant a connected regular graph. I have edited the question.

Comment: @Ranveer Singh: if you want connected, take the complement of the above examples.

Comment: @ChrisGodsil I understood that the complement of the above graphs (let's say disjoint union of two cycles of a different order) is a regular graph, call it $G$. But I don't think it will give a counterexample that the graphs $H_1$, $H_2$ obtained from $G$ are isomorphic, atleast degree sequence of $H_1, H_2$ is the same no matter what vertex we remove.